# CSS3 Selectors - style hashtag-words

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've searched a lot, but still cant find a way to use CSS3 Selectors to style all words starting with a #... Like #diy. Shouldnt that be possible using css-only?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: You can't wrap a `<span>` or something similar around them when you, using whatever you use, write them to the page?

Comment: I don't know why people prefer to do everything with CSS. Javascript was designed to perform all these tasks and it does handsomely.

Comment: @Muhammad Talha Akbar: It's not like *applying styles* is something CSS wasn't designed to do. It just happens to be severely limited in this aspect.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, right sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but it can quite easily be done with JavaScript.

Using [Extend jQuery.highlight to highlight regular expressions](http://beatgates.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/extend-jqueryhighlight-to-highlight.html):

```
$('body').highlight(/\B#\w+/)
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/ttd9r/

Comment: Thanks!I dont really understand the "/\B#\w+/" beside I can see I can change the # to a @. Can can I make sure I highlight both @ and #?

Comment: @MortenHjort - I can't edit at the moment, but have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp . You can use `/\B[@#]\w+/`.

Answer (score 3):

Selectors aren't designed for selecting text content directly in part or in full, so no, it shouldn't.

Selectors are designed for matching elements. If you want to style hashtags differently, you should be wrapping them in their own elements and then styling those elements.